# Different Status Message templates for different pages

Tags: 8, status-messages

I have been trying to use different status message templates. But I do not know if we can use different status message templates for different pages.  Is it possible?

Right now, I am using

```
status-messages.html.twig
```

Any help would highly be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example adding routename to status messages' templates suggestions (you may also add some parameters or whatever you need)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_status_messages_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $suggestions[] = 'status_messages__'.str_replace('.','_', $route->getRouteName());
}
```

This way you can have `status-messages--[routename].html.twig` as a template, and if this file not exists, have a fallback to `status-messages.html.twig`

Comment: umm doesn't all nodes have the same route name...

Comment: That's probably why i talked about parameters -that `$route` contains- : i gave an example about how to do it, i'm pretty sure that an @InspiredCoder can add more suggestions and fit his needs this way :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was wondering how template suggestions would work for status message. You're the man Oulalahakabu  :)

Comment: Note it works always the same, just replace HOOK in  `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter` by the hook you see in debug mode. You may also use `hook_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook){}`